# How can i know the newest APIs for twitter?

Tags: android, api, twitter

**hey everybody,**
i want to ask about **user information twitter API** as i used in my app this

```
        String url="https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name="+name;
```

but the result was

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}
```

can any one help me to get the API v1.1 syntax as i searched alot but i couldn't get an answer ..

Comment: what did you search for? https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public seems to be decent documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for twitter Developer's Guide.Here is the list of API's,

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: thanks fazal for your answer, but i still couldn't find the correct one i already tried this before https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search but i got this error

{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Comment: This is the code to search Username in twitter API 1.1    `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?screen_name="+name`